# how does the method .remove make difference in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```py
a = [(1, 1), (35, 1), (1, 35), (35,35)]

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

then it prints

> (1, 1)
> (35, 1)
> (1, 35)
> (35, 35)

however this code , though I expected the same result

```py
a = [(1, 1), (35, 1), (1, 35), (35,35)]

for i in a:
   a.remove(i)
   print(i)
```

then the result is

> (1, 1)
> (1, 35)

How can the method `.remove` make this difference? I have no idea how it works. Please help me!

Comment: Never modify the list you're currently iterating over - the iterator won't notice that you've modified it, and have weird behavior like this. Always either iterate over a copy, or do the iteration and removal in two separate steps. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Answer (score 1):

`.remove` makes a difference because you are updating the iterator as it interates.

**Imagine** `i` as a pointer which points to the `0`th index of `a` and goes till the end of `length(a)`.(Here, `length(a)` is itself changing).

So your code is like:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for i in a:
    a.remove(i)
    print(i)
```

So **internally** , `i` is initialised to point to the `0`th index of `a` in the first iteration.

In the next iteration, `i` is automatically initialised to point to the  `1`st index of `a` (if it exists)

In the next iteration, `i` is is automatically initialised to point to the `2`nd index of `a` (if it exists) and so on...

So here is what happens in the loop:

### Iteration 1

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
i -> 0th index of a = 1

a.remove(i)
a -> [2, 3, 4]

print(i) -> prints 1
```

### Iteration  2

```
a = [2, 3, 4]
i -> 1st index of a = 3

a.remove(i)
a -> [2, 4]

print(i) -> prints 3
```

### Iteration 3

```
a = [2, 4]
i -> 2nd index of a = Does not exist -> Quit iteration
```

Because of this, if you run the above program, only `1` and `3` will be printed.